# Angular ngTemplate, ngTemplateOutlet, ngContent: Select Contents of Template

Tags: angular, templates, css-selectors, ng-container, angular-content-projection

### Angular ngTemplate, ngTemplateOutlet, ngContent: Select Contents of Template

I have 2 components: `AppComponent` (`<app></app>`) and `ModalComponent` (`<modal></modal>`). Nothing is special about these other than:

- `ModalComponent` leverages `NgContent`
- `AppComponent` has a *Template* within its markup

modal.component.html

```html
<div class="modal">
    <header class="modal header">
        <ng-content select=".modal.header.title"></ng-content>
        <span class="header close">X</span>
    </header>
    <main class="modal body">
        <ng-content select=".modal.body.content"></ng-content>
    </main>
    <footer class="modal footer">
        <menu class="footer button group">
            <ng-content select=".modal.footer.button"></ng-content>
        </menu>
    </footer>
</div>
```

app.component.html

```html
<div id="whatTheWhat">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="tpl"></ng-container>
</div>

<modal>
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="tpl"></ng-container>
</modal>

<ng-template #tpl>
    <h1 class="modal header title">Modal Content Works!!!</h1>
    <div class="modal body content">
        ...
    </div>
    <button class="modal footer button">Confirm!</button>
</ng-template>
```

#### Expected Behavior

Each of the children within `[#tpl]` gets projected into each `ng-content` where `[select]` reflects the child's className.

#### Issue

None of the content gets project, with 1 exception:

- If I add `class="modal template"` to the `ng-container` and add `ng-content` with `[select]=".modal.template"` **then it works, but only *wholesale***. That is, the entirety of the template content gets projected into a single slot.

Moreover, if you look at `div#whatTheWhat` in a DOM Inspector, you'll see that each of the template's children becomes a *Direct Descendant* of `#whatTheWhat`. **This must mean that content-projection is occuring before 'outletting' the template**.

#### Additional

We are on Angular 10 but I believe I wrote this code virtually exact in an Angular 7 app (and it worked fine), but perhaps something has changed since Angular 8+.

Obviously, given the "exception" under "Issue" (above) I could fractionate my template into each of its children, `class`ify multiple `ng-container`s to reflect each `ng-conent`'s `select`ion, and have the content projected. If you've read this far, you can assume **that's not what I want**.

#### Question

Is there any way to "`select`ively project specific template content into another component"? Can you think of a way to accomplish this *even using native HTML elements such as `<template>` and `<slot>`*?